# How to get llistview item into webview?

Tags: android, listview, webview

i have a listview that im extracting from sharedpreferences data with urls,in each listview row there is a url that i want to send into my webview which is in another activity .
here is my webview activity

```
WebView webView;

String DEFAULT_URL = "https://www.google.co.in/";
ProgressDialog progressBar;
String YourWebName = "Put Here";
ArrayList<String> list;

String  bundle=null;
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webView= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String url = i.getStringExtra("link");

    prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit=prefs.edit();
    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    if (getIntent().getExtras()!=null &&getIntent().getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data")!=null){
        bundle=getIntent().getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");
        parseJson(bundle);
        Log.e("notificationData", ""+bundle);
    }else{
        showProgressBar();
        webView.loadUrl(DEFAULT_URL);
    }


}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (progressBar!=null && progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

**and here is my listview activity**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_notifications);

    no_notifications=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.no_notifications);

    prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //edit=prefs.edit();
    listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

     listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
           String str=(String)o;
              Toast.makeText(ListOfNotifications.this, "You have chosen: " + " " + str.getLabel(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Intent i = new Intent(ListOfNotifications.this,ParseStarterProjectActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("link", o.getText());

            startActivity(i);
       }
     });
    if (getIntent().getExtras()!=null &&getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("listData")!=null){

    listData=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("listData");

    if (listData!=null && listData.size()>0){
        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        no_notifications.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter= new ListAdapter(ListOfNotifications.this, R.layout.listview_row,listData);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }else{
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        no_notifications.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the url into the intent from the list activity to the webview activity.
get that url from intent in webview activity and pass that url in `loadUrl(url)` of webview.

This will work.

Comment: Are you getting any error? or what is happening can you tell me?